# How to control scrolling of a canvas with other scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project for which i have created an example in which i want to control scrolling actions of a canvas from other custom scrollbar which i have made.

In this code i have made a division which has two more div in it of which one contains two canvas and another one contains scrollber

i want my canvas-myCanvas1 to be controlled by the scrollbar which i have made

```js
var ctx;
var canvas;

function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
  var words = text.split(' ');
  var line = '';

  for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
    var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;
    if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      line = words[n] + ' ';
      y += lineHeight;
    } else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }

  context.fillText(line, x, y);
}
window.onload = function() {
  canvas1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
  ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  canvas2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
  ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
  ctx1.font = "18px Arial";
  ctx2.font = "18px Arial";
  var maxWidth = 400;
  var lineHeight = 25;
  var x = (canvas1.width - maxWidth) / 2;
  var y = 60;
  var text = "Stephen William Hawking CH CBE FRS FRSA (8 January 1942 – 14 March 2018) was an English theoretical physicist, cosmologist, and author who was director of research at the Centre for Theoretical Cosmology at the University of Cambridge at the time of his death.[17][18][7] He was the Lucasian Professor of Mathematics at the University of Cambridge between 1979 and 2009.His scientific works included a collaboration with Roger Penrose on gravitational singularity theorems in the framework of general relativity and the theoretical prediction that black holes emit radiation, often called Hawking radiation. Hawking was the first to set out a theory of cosmology explained by a union of the general theory of relativity and quantum mechanics. He was a vigorous supporter of the many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics.Hawking achieved commercial success with several works of popular science in which he discusses his own theories and cosmology in general. His book A Brief History of Time appeared on the British Sunday Times best-seller list for a record-breaking 237 weeks. Hawking was a Fellow of the Royal Society (FRS), a lifetime member of the Pontifical Academy of Sciences, and a recipient of the Presidential Medal of Freedom, the highest civilian award in the United States. In 2002, Hawking was ranked number 25 in the BBC's poll of the 100 Greatest Britons.In 1963, Hawking was diagnosed with an early-onset slow-progressing form of motor neurone disease (MND; also known as amyotrophic lateral sclerosis ALS or Lou Gehrig's disease) that gradually paralysed him over the decades.[21][22] Even after the loss of his speech, he was still able to communicate through a speech-generating device, initially through use of a hand-held switch, and eventually by using a single cheek muscle. He died on 14 March 2018 at the age of 76, after living with the disease for more than 50 years.";
  wrapText(ctx1, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight);
  ctx2.fillText("CANVAS", 250, 250);

}
```

```css
.scrollbar {
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: right;
  height: 600px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #fbfbfb69;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.force-overflow {
  min-height: 800px;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #555;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<center>
  <div height="700" width="500" style="background-color: #fbfbfb69">
    <div class="left" style="max-height: 600px;max-width: width window;overflow: hidden;" onscroll="oninput">
      <canvas id="myCanvas1" height="1100px" width="600px" style="background-color: #fbfbfb69; "></canvas>
      <canvas id="myCanvas2" height="600" width="600" style="background-color: #fbfbfb69"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollbar right" id="style-1">
      <div id='myId' class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgR8J.png)

Comment: FYI `<center>` is obsolete and shouldn't be used

Comment: @j08691 i will remove it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a div element, you can simply use a [css range slider element](https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html?from=timeline&isappinstalled=0) on Canvas2.
As far as I know css in the link works for firefox, chrome and IE, just modify slightly for different appearance. 
Notice that you have to write css for all types of browser, otherwise the appearance would not be consistent.

Html would be like:

```
<input type="range" min="minVal" max="maxVal" ...>
```

Comment: that's not the solution to my problem